# arithmetics optimisation inside C for-loop

Tags: for-loop, optimization, arithmetic-expressions

I have two functions with for-loops, which look very similar. The number of data to process is very large, so I am trying to optimise the cycles as much as possible. The execution time for the second function is 320 sec, but the first one takes 460 sec. Could somebody please give me any suggestions what makes the difference and how to optimise the computation?

```
    int ii, jj;
    double c1, c2;

    for (ii = 0; ii < n; ++ii) {
        a[jj] += b[ii] * c1;
        a[++jj] += b[ii] * c2;
    }
```

The second one:

```
    int ii, jj;
    double c1, c2;

    for (ii = 0; ii < n; ++ii) {
        b[ii] += a[jj] * c1;
        b[ii] += a[++jj] * c2;
    }
```

And here is the assembler output for the first loop:

```
    movl    -104(%rbp), %eax
    movq    -64(%rbp), %rcx
    cmpl    (%rcx), %eax
    jge LBB0_12
## BB#10:                               ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_9 Depth=5
    movslq  -88(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rcx
    movsd   (%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0    ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    mulsd   -184(%rbp), %xmm0
    movslq  -108(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -224(%rbp), %rcx        ## 8-byte Reload
    addsd   (%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rcx,%rax,8)
    movslq  -88(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rdx
    movsd   (%rdx,%rax,8), %xmm0    ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    mulsd   -192(%rbp), %xmm0
    movl    -108(%rbp), %esi
    addl    $1, %esi
    movl    %esi, -108(%rbp)
    movslq  %esi, %rax
    addsd   (%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rcx,%rax,8)
    movl    -88(%rbp), %esi
    addl    $1, %esi
    movl    %esi, -88(%rbp)
```

and for the second one:

```
    movl    -104(%rbp), %eax
    movq    -64(%rbp), %rcx
    cmpl    (%rcx), %eax
    jge LBB0_12
## BB#10:                               ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_9 Depth=5
    movslq  -108(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -224(%rbp), %rcx        ## 8-byte Reload
    movsd   (%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0    ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    mulsd   -184(%rbp), %xmm0
    movslq  -88(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rdx
    addsd   (%rdx,%rax,8), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax,8)
    movl    -108(%rbp), %esi
    addl    $1, %esi
    movl    %esi, -108(%rbp)
    movslq  %esi, %rax
    movsd   (%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0    ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    mulsd   -192(%rbp), %xmm0
    movslq  -88(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rdx
    addsd   (%rdx,%rax,8), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax,8)
    movl    -88(%rbp), %esi
    addl    $1, %esi
    movl    %esi, -88(%rbp)
```

The original function is much bigger, so here I provided only the pieces responsible for those for-loops. The rest of the c-code and its assembler output is exactly the same for both functions.

Comment: Could you tag your question with the correct language?

Comment: You may want to look at the assembler (if any) generated.

Comment: That is clearly unoptimized code (-O0), could you post the proper optimized assembly?

Comment: I tried different levels of optimization, but it did not help at all. The -O1 and -O2 optimizations even slow down the computations, and -O3 optimization have pretty much the same speed as -O0. The computation time for the loops modified according to your suggestions and compiled using -O3 optimization level is  - 440 and 320 sec.

Comment: I want to provide the assembler output for -O3 optimization level, but it became too long and complicated, and the loop is split in two parts in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of that calculation is pretty weird, but it can be optimized significantly. Some problems with that code are

- reloading data from a pointer after writing to an other pointer that isn't known to not alias. I assume they won't alias because this algorithm would be even weirder if that was allowed, but if they're really supposed to maybe alias, ignore this. In general, structure your loop body as: first load everything, do calculations, then store back. Don't mix loading and storing, it makes the compiler more conservative.
- reloading data that was stored in the previous iteration. The compiler can see through this a bit, but it complicates matters. Don't do it.
- implicitly treating the first and last items differently. It looks like a nice homogeneous loop at first, but due to its weird structure it's actually special casing the first and last things.

So let's first fix the second loops, which is simpler. The only problem here is the first store to `b[ii]`, which has to Really Happen<sup>(tm)</sup> because it might alias with `a[jj + 1]`. But it can trivially be written so that that problem goes away:

```
for (ii = 0; ii < n; ++ii) {
    b[ii] += a[jj] * c1 + a[jj + 1] * c2;
    jj++;
}
```

You can tell by the assembly output that the compiler is happier now, and of course benchmarking confirms it's faster.

Old asm (only main loop, not the extra cruft):

```
.LBB0_14:                               # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    vmulpd  ymm4, ymm2, ymmword ptr [r8 - 8]
    vaddpd  ymm4, ymm4, ymmword ptr [rax]
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rax], ymm4
    vmulpd  ymm5, ymm3, ymmword ptr [r8]
    vaddpd  ymm4, ymm4, ymm5
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rax], ymm4
    add     r8, 32
    add     rax, 32
    add     r11, -4
    jne     .LBB0_14
```

New asm (only main loop):

```
.LBB1_20:                               # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    vmulpd  ymm4, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rax - 104]
    vmulpd  ymm5, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rax - 72]
    vmulpd  ymm6, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rax - 40]
    vmulpd  ymm7, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rax - 8]
    vmulpd  ymm8, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rax - 96]
    vmulpd  ymm9, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rax - 64]
    vmulpd  ymm10, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rax - 32]
    vmulpd  ymm11, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rax]
    vaddpd  ymm4, ymm4, ymm8
    vaddpd  ymm5, ymm5, ymm9
    vaddpd  ymm6, ymm6, ymm10
    vaddpd  ymm7, ymm7, ymm11
    vaddpd  ymm4, ymm4, ymmword ptr [rcx - 96]
    vaddpd  ymm5, ymm5, ymmword ptr [rcx - 64]
    vaddpd  ymm6, ymm6, ymmword ptr [rcx - 32]
    vaddpd  ymm7, ymm7, ymmword ptr [rcx]
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rcx - 96], ymm4
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rcx - 64], ymm5
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rcx - 32], ymm6
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rcx], ymm7
    sub     rax, -128
    sub     rcx, -128
    add     rbx, -16
    jne     .LBB1_20
```

That also got unrolled more (automatically), but the more significant difference (not that unrolling is useless, but reducing the loop overhead isn't such a big deal usually, it can mostly be handled by the ports that aren't busy with vector instructions) is the reduction in stores, which takes it from a ratio of 2/3 (potentially bottlenecked by store throughput where half the stores are useless) to 4/12 (bottlenecked by something that really has to happen).

Now for that first loop, once you take out the first and last iterations, it's just adding two scaled `b`'s to every `a`, and then we put the first and last iterations back in separately:

```
a[0] += b[0] * c1;
for (ii = 1; ii < n; ++ii) {
    a[ii] += b[ii - 1] * c2 + b[ii] * c1;
}
a[n] += b[n - 1] * c2;
```

That takes it from this (note that this isn't even vectorized):

```
.LBB0_3:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    vmulsd  xmm3, xmm0, qword ptr [rsi + 8*rax]
    vaddsd  xmm2, xmm2, xmm3
    vmovsd  qword ptr [rdi + 8*rax], xmm2
    vmulsd  xmm2, xmm1, qword ptr [rsi + 8*rax]
    vaddsd  xmm2, xmm2, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rax + 8]
    vmovsd  qword ptr [rdi + 8*rax + 8], xmm2
    vmulsd  xmm3, xmm0, qword ptr [rsi + 8*rax + 8]
    vaddsd  xmm2, xmm2, xmm3
    vmovsd  qword ptr [rdi + 8*rax + 8], xmm2
    vmulsd  xmm2, xmm1, qword ptr [rsi + 8*rax + 8]
    vaddsd  xmm2, xmm2, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rax + 16]
    vmovsd  qword ptr [rdi + 8*rax + 16], xmm2
    lea     rax, [rax + 2]
    cmp     ecx, eax
    jne     .LBB0_3
```

To this:

```
.LBB1_6:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    vmulpd  ymm4, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rbx - 104]
    vmulpd  ymm5, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rbx - 72]
    vmulpd  ymm6, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rbx - 40]
    vmulpd  ymm7, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rbx - 8]
    vmulpd  ymm8, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rbx - 96]
    vmulpd  ymm9, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rbx - 64]
    vmulpd  ymm10, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rbx - 32]
    vmulpd  ymm11, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rbx]
    vaddpd  ymm4, ymm4, ymm8
    vaddpd  ymm5, ymm5, ymm9
    vaddpd  ymm6, ymm6, ymm10
    vaddpd  ymm7, ymm7, ymm11
    vaddpd  ymm4, ymm4, ymmword ptr [rcx - 96]
    vaddpd  ymm5, ymm5, ymmword ptr [rcx - 64]
    vaddpd  ymm6, ymm6, ymmword ptr [rcx - 32]
    vaddpd  ymm7, ymm7, ymmword ptr [rcx]
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rcx - 96], ymm4
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rcx - 64], ymm5
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rcx - 32], ymm6
    vmovupd ymmword ptr [rcx], ymm7
    sub     rbx, -128
    sub     rcx, -128
    add     r11, -16
    jne     .LBB1_6
```

Nice and vectorized this time, and much less storing and loading going on.

Both changes combined made it about twice as fast on my PC but of course YMMV.

I still that this code is weird though. Note how we're modifying `a[n]` in the last iteration of the first loop, then use it in the first iteration of the second loop, while the other `a`'s just sort of stand to side and watch. It's odd. Maybe it really has to be that way, but frankly it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry that I did not explain that before but those two loops comes from different functions which are supposed to do the opposite things, and I just want to find out why the first function takes longer than the second one. I modified the loops according to your recommendations. The progress is 430 sec for the first function and 310 sec for the second one. I use iMac 2010 for the computations and compile the functions as MATLAB MEX-files with a gcc compiler, may be this does matter. Later today I will prepare the assembler output for my functions and post it here.

Comment: @user6931236 ok it makes more sense now. As for the difference, it's because it compiles to worse code. After the modifications as shown here there is probably no difference, but it would be interesting if there were

Comment: Even after I modified the codes, there is still a significant difference in computation speed: 310 vs 430 sec, and the modifications gave only a small speed increase for both of the functions (before it was 320 vs 460). I have provided the assembler output for my functions. As for me they look very similar - the same commands, just a different order, but the computation speed significantly differs. Bad for me I am not familiar with assembler at all.